Question views not updating?
My recent question has received three upvotes, yet it shows only 2 views.  This seems wrong, as I understand views.  Here's my screenshot (from Google Chrome):


I suspect caching...

2 other users mentioned in chat that they were also seeing 2 views and 3 votes.

I meant server side caching, which Stack Exchange does heavily.

Server side caching certainly makes sense, but I thought it worth clarifying that I checked to make sure that the issue wasn't strictly client side (or specific to my browser installation/configuration).

It's very likely caching. I don't see any problem right now.

I remember a podcast or blog post where Jef Atwood (or Joel Spolsky?) explained that the number of views is a very crude estimation of how many people have viewed the question. They claimed the actual number of views is almost always considerably more, if not twice as much. 
Apparently they are very conservative in their estimates. Their estimation algorithm could be updated based on this 'bug' though. :) It's a minor detail but it seems easily actionable.
